# Access Key Vault Certificate from Azure Function using Java

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-java-sdk

I have a Azure Function In Java. Using Managed Identity and Key Vault reference, I have added a configuration in function app to access the key vault secret and certificate. The secret is referenced correctly and I am able to access its value in Azure Function.

When accessing the certificate from Azure Key Vault,
using System.getenv(, I get a string which is encoded. How can I convert that string into a valid certificate in pfx or pem format.

Is there any other way to securely access certificate from Azure Key Vault in the Azure function using Java as runtime language.

Comment: Hello @the_eagle, may I know if you have referred this SO thread : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599001/azure-function-key-vault-reference-for-certificates

Comment: Hi @RamaraoAdapa-MT, I have referred this thread. The ans is for .NET. I tried a similar approach using Java (my runtime stack.)
But I get an error.
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1822)
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:184)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:105)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:355)

Comment: byte[] encodedCert = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certB64);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream  =  new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedCert);
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
             cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Above is my time code in Java. 
The value in certB64 is the string returned as config variable from Key vault

Comment: Please try with below code : 
byte[] encodedCert = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certB64.replaceAll(X509Factory.BEGIN_CERT, "").replaceAll(X509Factory.END_CERT, ""));
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedCert); 
X509Certificate cert = null; 
try { 
 CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
 cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream); 
 } 
catch (CertificateException e) {
 e.printStackTrace(); 
 }
Let me know if it  works

Comment: Update: the code I have put decodes the string and generates a x509 cert correctly. The issue is when we have a managed identity activated and a proper access policy to Get Certificates, the base64 string that is returned is actually not valid. Online tools like cert decoder confirmed that. I am not sure what is returned through the configuration variable when we assign a managed identity and access policy as in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599001/azure-function-key-vault-reference-for-certificates.
String certString = System.getenv("getCert");

Comment: Please refer this to retrieve a certificate from keyvault : 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-security-keyvault-certificates#retrieve-a-certificate
As per the question, How can I convert that string into a valid certificate in pfx or pem format is resolved.

so, please update the question with the issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion in the comment section, to convert the base 64 string into a valid certificate in pfx or pem format, please use below code :

```
byte[] encodedCert = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certB64.replaceAll(X509Factory.BEGIN_CERT, "").replaceAll(X509Factory.END_CERT, "")); 
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedCert); 
X509Certificate cert = null; 
try { 
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509"); 
cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
} 
catch (CertificateException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

You can refer this to retrieve a certificate from keyvault : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-security-keyvault-certificates#retrieve-a-certificate

Comment: This code shows error on X509Factory. However, the code works. 
But a better way that i have figured is that each certificate has a secret if. Using client libraries we can get the secret id and fetch the certString using getSecret(<cert name>).

Comment: Currently, one issue I am facing is that while deploying azure function the build fails if some variables are specified in configuration settings in Azure Function App portal. 
There are service principal credentials which I am taking as env variables. However while deploying locally, it does not picks up those values and hence non-null exception is there

Comment: this is the error message. The build fails
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must provide non-null values for clientId, tenantId, clientSecret properties in ClientSecretCredentialBuilder