# Python: Azure Function Key Vault reference for certificates?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599001/azure-function-key-vault-reference-for-certificates), I have a Python Azure Function where I want to load a certificate from a Key Vault Reference. Referencing the secret returns a string that looks like this: `"MIIcGA...z62QICB9A="`. I'm trying to load this into an azure.identity CertificateCredential object and can't figure out how to construct the correct `certificate_data`

My actual call looks like this:

```
from azure.identity import CertificateCredential
cert_cred = CertificateCredential("72f...guid", "eff...guid", certificate_data = str.encode(cert64))
```

I've tried wrapping my cert64 string in `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` but whatever I do, I get the error `Failed to deserialize certificate in PEM or PKCS12 format`

I tried reworking my certificate string to be split with newlines at 64chars so it looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIcGAIBAzCCG9QGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCG8UEghvBMIIbvTCCBhYGCSqGSIb3DQEH
AaCCBgcEggYDMIIF/zCCBfsGCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIE/jCCBPowHAYKKoZIhvcN
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Using this code

```
final_cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
for i in re.findall('.?'*64, cert64 ):
    final_cert += "\r\n" + i
final_cert += "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
print (final_cert)
```

I get a slightly different error message:
`Exception has occurred: ValueError Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format or it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm.`

Comment: What version of `azure-identity` are you using? The error that you're seeing is only raised in [this method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/azure-identity_1.11.0/sdk/identity/azure-identity/azure/identity/_credentials/certificate.py#L88) in the latest stable version, which suggests that the certificate isn't being recognized as being in PEM format. For reference, [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/azure-identity_1.11.0/sdk/identity/azure-identity/tests/certificate-with-password.pem) is a PEM certificate used for testing the CertificateCredential.

Comment: I'm using azure-identity 1.7.0 but the issue repros on 1.11.0 as well. I feel like the issue is that I'm not doing the right thing with this certificate string which I fetched from keyvault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fighting with this all day, I discovered the answer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/samples/key_vault_cert.py)

Base64-decode the string that comes from keyvault and set it as the certificate_data bytes.

```
pkcs12_bytes = base64.b64decode(cert64)   
cert_cred = CertificateCredential("72f...guid", "eff...guid", certificate_data = base64.b64decode(cert64))
```